# Is it able to only allow yanked content went to clipboard, meanwhile deleted content doesn't? [vim]

Tags: vim

I got `set clipboard=unnamed` in my vimrc.
Thus I can move vim's content to clipboard easily.

But recently, I found I don't need the deleted content(with `d`, `x`,  etc.) went to sys-clipboard,
since it causes me some inconvenience.

I read the vim's `register help info` through this afternoon.
And found that `"0` is for yanked content in vim, and `"1` is for deleted content.

But in the clipboard help interface, I saw the only 2 option are  `set clipboard=unnamed` and  `set clipboard=unnamedplus`.

Is there a way that I can set clipboard to `"0`, or only allow yanked content went to register `"*` and `"+`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing built-in, but you can implement such by overriding all yank commands to temporarily `:set clipboard=unnamed`. (I wouldn't do it the other way around because there are many more commands that implicitly delete, like `c`, `s`, `x`, `d`, ...)

The mappings can be quite simple, like

```
:nnoremap <silent> yy :<C-u>set clipboard=unnamed<Bar>execute 'normal!' v:count1 . 'yy'<Bar>set clipboard=<CR>
```

`y{motion}` is a bit more challenging; either you implement a full custom operator function (see `:help g@`), or you use an `:autocmd CursorMoved` trigger to reset the `'clipboard'` option.

Comment: But the motion yank stuff is the big part. If I use the method you mentioned above. I think I got to do lost of mapping to `y[n]k`, `y[n]l`, `y[n]h`, `y[n]j`, `y[n]G`, `y[n]y`, `y[n]b`, `y[n]w`. OK, assuming I'll do all of this. I still got no specific plan to implement the second suggestion you mentioned above. Could you recommend me some reading-source, so that after read which, I could know how to use `custom operator function`, or better, have a full picture in my mind of how vim/vi works?

Comment: No, that's certainly not how you would do it! There's an example at `:h g@`; you can also look at my [RepeatableYank plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4238).

Comment: I've reviewed your first yy command, and have some small confusion. What does the `<C-u>` do here, calling command mode? And `v:count1` means count one line from current line?

Comment: `<C-u>` make you handle a prepended count (`4yy`), and `v:count1` is that count, reinserted.